# Find difference between two characters in SQL

Tags: sql, string, difference, cpu-word, letter

I have a table with 2 columns

```
column1   column2
abcd      abdc
abcr      dfgh
cvge      cbge
```

I want to know the sql query to get a third column with the results showing the difference between the 2 fields in such a way

```
column1   column2    calculated field
abcd      abdc       2
abcr      dfgh       0
cvge      cbge       3
```

Comment: SQL is not a suitable tool for this type of query, although it is possible.  You need to indicate what database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the fields are always four characters, you can use a `case` expression.  It is something like this:

```
select ( (case when substr(field1, 1, 1) = substr(field2, 1, 1) then 1 else 0 end) +
         (case when substr(field1, 2, 1) = substr(field2, 2, 1) then 1 else 0 end) +
         (case when substr(field1, 3, 1) = substr(field2, 3, 1) then 1 else 0 end) +
         (case when substr(field1, 4, 1) = substr(field2, 4, 1) then 1 else 0 end)
       ) as calculated
```

Note that all databases support the functionality of `substr()`, but in some databases, the function might have a different name.